# Can I use a custom post type as a custom taxonomy for a different custom post type?

Tags: plugin-development

I am working on a site and need some guidance on how to proceed.

The site allows registration of (1) artists, (2) promotion teams, and (3) members. The site hosts talent expos in which artists registered are assigned a promotion team and posts an .mp3. The promo teams recruits voters and organizes concerts etc for their artist to encourage voting. Users vote daily on their favorite .mp3 in a "faceoff competition."

If I create a custom post type of "competing_artist," a registered artist could register for an expo and upload their .mp3. I could assign the 10 selected competing artists ( and their corresponding promo team ( as another custom post type ) to the expo "post" to relate the three.

I think this would allow me to display an expo that would have all the competing artists, be able to add information about the expo (like location, etc), and enable me to equip the staff with easy gui to select the necessary components of the expo.

Is this the WordPress way or is there another and better way???

Answer (score 1):

The plugin [CPTonomies](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cpt-onomies/) is designed to exactly this. There is no built-in Wordpress way to do this.

I've never tried to make Wordpress do this, but this is the plugin I've seen used by others trying to achieve this functionality. You might also try [Posts 2 Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/), which creates relationships between different post types instead of doubling a post type title as a taxonomy.